# How is every D-brane dual to 2 others?

Tags: boundary-conditions, ads-cft, duality

For instance, A D3 brane is T dual to both a D2 and D4. I understand the idea that Type A and B theories are T dual to one another, but I don't understand how you get 2 different dual descriptions starting from 1.

Comment: you may T-dualise one of the cycles the brane is wrapping, or one it isn't wrapping. It's not simultaneously dual to both a D2 and a D4, but it can be dual to either.

Comment: Wow, thank you that clarified a lot. @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə